# MongoDB aggregate in PHP, adding seconds to date/time

Tags: php, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a `MongoDB` aggregate in `PHP` defined as:

```
$results = $c->aggregate(array(
    array(
      '$project' => array(
          'year' => array('$year' => array('$add' => array('$executed.getTime()', 3600))),
          'month' => array('$month' => array('$add' => array('$executed.getTime()', 3600))),
          'day' => array('$dayOfMonth' => array('$add' => array('$executed.getTime()', 3600)))
      ),
    ),
    array(
      '$group' => array(
          '_id' => array('year' => '$year', 'month' => '$month', 'day' => '$day'),
          'count' => array('$sum' => 1)
      ),
    ),
    array(
      '$sort' => array(
          '_id' => 1
      ),
    ),
    array(
      '$limit' => 30
    )
));
```

The problem is that the `$add` aggregate function in `$project` is not working.

```
 exception: the $year operator does not accept an object as an operand
```

What is the correct way to add an arbitrary number of seconds to the date/time field `$executed`?

Thanks.

Comment: Is not working - in what way?

Comment: Array
(
    [errmsg] => exception: the $year operator does not accept an object as an operand
    [code] => 16021
    [ok] => 0
)

Comment: Is $executed a field in your document or is it something you expect to exist as a constant and doesn't? Either way you can't use the functions in the aggregate like that

Comment: `$executed` is the field name, a MongoDB BSON date/time.

Comment: Ok It seems `$add` does not yet support dates. Hmm you will need to find another way around this.

Comment: Yeah, the aggregation pipeline has very limited support for manipulating dates.   For a slightly different approach take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14555140/mongodb-group-function-or-map-reduce-if-necessary-with-php-distinct-keys/14556712#14556712 Are you in the same class?  I hope this isn't a take-home-final :)

Comment: MongoDB aggregates are super frustrating. I need to completely rework this.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're seeing is a bug in MongoDB, which I've reported in [SERVER-9289](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-9289). A work-around for this entails wrapping the argument to the date operator in an array, as in the following shell example:

```
> db.foo.drop()

> db.foo.insert({x:ISODate()})

> db.foo.aggregate({$project: {x:1, y: {$year: {$add:['$x',1000]}}}})
Error: Printing Stack Trace
    at printStackTrace (src/mongo/shell/utils.js:37:7)
    at DBCollection.aggregate (src/mongo/shell/collection.js:897:1)
    at (shell):1:8
Mon Apr  8 18:15:15.198 JavaScript execution failed: aggregate failed: {
    "errmsg" : "exception: the $year operator does not accept an object as an operand",
    "code" : 16021,
    "ok" : 0
} at src/mongo/shell/collection.js:L898

> db.foo.aggregate({$project: {x:1, y: {$year: [{$add:['$x',1000]}]}}})
{
    "result" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("516341333512acfb2d33f156"),
            "x" : ISODate("2013-04-08T22:14:11.665Z"),
            "y" : 2013
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

It should be trivial to port that over to PHP.

Having said that, your original code does have a bug in the reference to `$executed`. Per the [$project](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/project/#project-aggregation) documentation, you can refer to fields in the BSON document by name (or a dotted path to a field within objects/arrays), but there is no support for invoking JavaScript methods on those fields. Along those lines, the aggregation pipeline is operating on the raw BSON documents, so those types are never translated into their JavaScript representations over the course of the pipeline (e.g. the BSON date never becomes an ISODate).

Thankfully, calling `$executed.getTime()` should not even be necessary with MongoDB 2.4. [SERVER-6239](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-6239) improved support for BSON date handling in `$add` and `$subtract`. You can see that ticket for more details, such as the expected result for subtracting two dates, or adding a date and a number.